# Change values in Python file (tab-delimited list)

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I have read a `*.INP` file into Python. Here is the code I used:

```
import csv

r = csv.reader(open('T_JAC.INP')) # Here your csv file
lines = [l for l in r]

print lines[23]
print lines[26]
```

The **first** `print` statement produces `['9E21\t\texthere (text) text alphabets text alphanumeric']`.

The **second** `print` statement produces `['4E15\t\texthere (text) text alphabets text alphanumeric']`.

I need to change the numbers `7E21` and `4E15`. I need to change them to values from a list `fil_replace = [9E21,6E15]`.i.e. I need to replace `7E21` to `9E21` and I need to change `4E21` to `6E21`.

Is there a way to replace these numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something with [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) should work (as long as you read `r` in as a string), albeit not the most efficient solution:

```
r.replace('7E21', '9E21')

file = open('YAC.IN', 'w')
file.write(r)
file.close()
```

If you're looking for a way to just replace the values 'in place' in the file unfortunately it's not possible. The entire file has to be read in, modified, then re-written.

Comment: Thank you. I have rarely used `replace()` before. This did not occur to me. That answers the question. EDIT: I altered the OP to reflect the correct file name.